# Using a DSLR camera as a webcam to stream on OBS

Tags: video, webcam, canon, camera, gphoto2

I've recently changed from Windows to Ubuntu and I'm trying to get my DSLR camera (Canon Rebel T3) to function as a webcam so I can make those cool videos about old racing games and its cars (remember the Renault Espace with an F1 engine from Gran Turismo 2?).

I've followed the steps from this [link](https://www.crackedthecode.co/how-to-use-your-dslr-as-a-webcam-in-linux/) and watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsuY4o2zLVQ) a couple of times, but when I try to insert this command:

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

It gives me this error:

```
ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument
Could not write header for outputfile #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

Or the terminal gets stuck.

The gphoto2 detects my camera and gives all the information about the camera, but when I try to take a picture, it doesn't save anywhere.

When I go to VLC, my camera isn't in the capture devices, so something might be wrong I guess.

Also, when I try to edit the /etc/modules to register the modprobe, I'm unable to edit anything. I imagine there is something wrong, but since I'm an early Ubuntu user, maybe it's the lack of knowledge.

Attached to this post is my [system configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gebpg.png) (maybe that's what's causing the issue).

Kind regards,

Comment: Try other pixel formats. yuv420p is not the only one and your cam may not support it.

Comment: Also try `ffplay /dev/video0` to see if it can be played. If it can, launch it again in verbose log mode to see what pixel format it is using